# The probability that neither team score

Tags: probability

In a football match , the probability that team A scores first is $0.6$ , and the probability that team B scores first is $0.35$ .

The probability that team A scores first and wins the match is $0.48$ .

a) Find the probability that team A scores first and does not win the match .

If team B scores first , the probability that team A will win the match is $0.3$ .

b) Given that team A won the match, find the probability that they did not score first .

My turn :

a) $0.6 \times 0.2 = 0.12 $

b) For this part i need to find the probability of A wins the match and this my question

Comment: I agree with your answer in part $a)$ but I don't understand your method.  Why do you multiply by $.2$?

Comment: We are given enough information for $b)$.   Note that it is impossible for $A$ to win a game in which nobody scores, so the given information covers all the possible cases.

Comment: Do you mean the answer for part b is $0$ ? @lulu

Comment: Obviously not.  I am just saying that you can answer $b)$ using the given information. Indeed, you can use the given information to compute the probability that $A$ wins the match.  The key point being that, if $A$ wins the match then we know that somebody scored first.

Comment: For part a i multiplied by $0.2$ because $P(A scores and A does not win ) = P(A wins |A scores ) \times P(A scores) $ , $P(A wins | A scores) = \frac{0.48}{0.6} = 0.8 $ so $P(B wins | A scores ) = 0.2 $

Comment: I don't understand.   What you wrote is not correct.  If $X$ is the event "$A$ scores first" and $Y$ is the event "$A$ wins the match", then, by definition of conditional probability, we have $P(Y\,|\,X)=\frac {P(Y\cap X)}{P(X)}$ which is not equivalent to what you wrote.

Comment: Note that the given information does not allow us to compute the probability $B$ wins, conditioned on $A$ scoring first (or otherwise).  For all we know, it is impossible for $B$ to win....maybe all scenarios not covered in the problem result in draws.  Or maybe $B$ wins every game that $A$ doesn't (save for the $5\%$ of games in which nobody scores at all).  There is no way to tell from the given data.